# How to convert a video for a Samsung Tablet on OS X or Unix

Tags: macos, unix, tablet, video-conversion

I have different kinds of files, mostly MKV and MP4. They are in 720p (ca. 1280x800).

As far as I know, video for this my Samsung tablet should be 1024x768 maximum. It should also use the h.264 AVC codec. Which settings for ffmpeg or mencoder should I use? Any OS X program would be great too.

Comment: Your tablet has [out-of-the-box support](http://www.samsung.com/us/article/do-more-on-the-go-with-the-galaxy-tab-) for the playback (if the tab has it, sure that better tablets have it). A very good program to play video files in android is [MVideoPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=afzkl.development.mVideoPlayer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you re-encode videos, you will always lose quality. Depending on the content and the settings chosen, this can make your videos look really bad.

### Handbrake

If you still want or *need* to do it, you can download and install [**Handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr/).

Open your source video, open "Picture Settings". Here, select "Anamorphic – None", and change the width/height accordingly.

[image]

The rest of the options shouldn't matter that much. "H.264 AVC" is the default codec, so leave this selected. You can play with the "Constant quality" slider to reduce/improve the quality of your result videos.

Which options should you use?

- You can also choose the *iPad* preset and see if that works, as it already is optimized for the iPad's 1024x768 display.
- If Android doesn't support the output video, you can try with the *iPod Legacy* preset. iPod Legacy should use a very basic ("Baseline") profile that is [supported by Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Don't forget to change back the video size when you switch profiles.

When you're done, click the "Start" button to convert your video.

### FFmpeg

I was able to find a rather complicated [iPad preset](http://www.ioncannon.net/meta/1040/how-to-create-ipad-formatted-videos-using-handbrake-or-ffmpeg/) that might work on an Android tablet.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -acodec aac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -s 1024×768 \
-vcodec libx264 -b 1200k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
-partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -coder 0 \
-me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 1200k \
-maxrate 1200k -bufsize 1200k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' \
-qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 16:9 -r 30 -g 90 -async 2 \
output.mp4
```

If Android doesn't support the videos – as mentioned above – it's time to use another profile. Ubuntu also has a [documentation for encoding for Android](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidVideoEncoding), which you can probably adopt for the tablet. Generally, any [tutorial valid for the iPod](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/using-ffmpeg-to-encode-videos-for-the-ipod) should also be valid for an Android Tablet.

Comment: OMFG mate your my personal jesus christ!!! I've been googling so much today in search of these settings.. and it's really was hard to find some settings for ffmpeg!!

Comment: I hope these work for you, through the links you should get the idea. You can also copy the ffmpeg settings from Handbrake itself and play with them. Report back or even edit my answer if you have a working command!

Comment: ok issue solved, it was freaking easy. there are plenty software for mac which converts all video formats to mp4 h264 AVC + you need to set a bitrate it's urgent!! As far as I tested it works till 3Mb.. but I'm using 2Mb it's quite enought and it works.. and I found this setting by manually converting some demo FULL HD files.. I hate this tablet..throwed my money away...